# Python sort an array

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to sort a numpy array containing classes from a variable.

```
groups =['(0, 10]', '(10, 20]', '(100, 110]', '(110, 120]', '(120, 130]',
         '(130, 140]', '(140, 150]', '(150, 160]', '(160, 170]', '(170, 180]', 
         '(180, 190]', '(190, 200]', '(20, 30]', '(200, 210]', '(210, 220]', 
         '(230, 240]', '(30, 40]', '(40, 50]', '(50, 60]', '(60, 70]', 
         '(70, 80]', '(80, 90]', '(90, 100]']
```

I want this:

```
groups = ['(0, 10]', '(10, 20]','(30, 40]','(40, 50]', '(50, 60]', ...]
```

I tried this:

```
sort(groups)
```

but nothing........

Comment: NameError: name 'sort' is not defined

Comment: Was this array generate using `pandas.cut`?

Comment: Yes i used pandas.cut

Comment: Did you convert the resulting categories to a list of strings, or are these elements still of categorical dtype in your actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sorting function is `sorted`.  We'll use a key function to extract the numbers and convert them to a tuple of integers.

```
sorted(groups, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x[1:-1].split(','))))
```

Output:

```
['(0, 10]', '(10, 20]', '(20, 30]', '(30, 40]', '(40, 50]', '(50, 60]',
 '(60, 70]', '(70, 80]', '(80, 90]', '(90, 100]', '(100, 110]', '(110, 120]',
'(120, 130]', '(130, 140]', '(140, 150]', '(150, 160]', '(160, 170]', 
'(170, 180]', '(180, 190]', '(190, 200]', '(200, 210]', '(210, 220]', '(230, 240]']
```

Comment: It doesnt work... I want to find a way without losing the formation of the classes

Comment: @dimitrisGmk what do you mean by the 'formation' of the classes?  The key functions sorts them as if they were tuples but does not actually change the values.  `sorted` creates a new list, and doesn't modify the old one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to interpret your strings as tuples of numbers otherwise they will be sorted by lexicographical order (which would give the wrong result!):

```
def interpret_as_tuple(x):
    splitted = x.split(',')
    first = int(splitted[0].strip('( '))
    second = int(splitted[1].strip('] '))
    return first, second

groups.sort(key=interpret_as_tuple)

groups
```

returns:

```
['(0, 10]', '(10, 20]', '(20, 30]', '(30, 40]', '(40, 50]', '(50, 60]', '(60, 70]',
 '(70, 80]', '(80, 90]', '(90, 100]', '(100, 110]', '(110, 120]', '(120, 130]',
 '(130, 140]', '(140, 150]', '(150, 160]', '(160, 170]', '(170, 180]', '(180, 190]',
 '(190, 200]', '(200, 210]', '(210, 220]', '(230, 240]']
```

Answer (score -3):

There are two problems with your elements

- they are strings, not tuples of numbers
- the closing ] does not match the opening (

So, you first have to convert them

```
groups = [eval(group[:-1] + ')') for group in groups]
print(sorted(groups))
```

Comment: Avoid `eval` please.

Comment: I know, but can't think of a better way in this case

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is much safer